# Rajawali - load textures from model obj error

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, blender, rajawali

I'm trying to make an aplication that loads an 3d object.

when i load this object (http://rgcouto.net/alexandre/COKE/fineObj/), all works fine.
screenshot: http://rgcouto.net/alexandre/COKE/Screenshot_2013-01-10-15-04-42.png

But when i try load my object (http://rgcouto.net/alexandre/COKE/myObj/), exported from blender, the texture doesn't appear and the object is dark.. 
screenshot: http://rgcouto.net/alexandre/COKE/Screenshot_2013-01-10-15-02-27.png

What did I do wrong? 
What i have to do, to make my object appear with texture?

My Blend file:http://rgcouto.net/alexandre/COKE/blend/

My renderer:

```
public class ObjRenderer extends RajawaliRenderer {
    private static final String TAG = "renderer";
    private BaseObject3D mObjectGroup;
    Number3D mAccValues;

    public ObjRenderer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFrameRate(60);
        mAccValues = new Number3D();

}

protected void initScene() {

    // mLight = new DirectionalLight(1, -1, 1);
    // mLight.setPower(.9f);
    DirectionalLight light = new DirectionalLight(0, 0, 1);
    light.setPower(1);

    // light.setPosition(0, 20, -20);
    // light.setLookAt(0, 0, 0);

    mCamera.setPosition(0, 0, -14);
    mCamera.setLookAt(0, 0, 0);

    ObjParser objParser = new ObjParser(mContext.getResources(),
            mTextureManager, R.raw.camaro_obj);
    objParser.parse();
    mObjectGroup = objParser.getParsedObject();
    Log.d(TAG, "carreguei");
    DiffuseMaterial material = new DiffuseMaterial();
    material.setUseColor(true);
    mObjectGroup.setMaterial(material);
    mObjectGroup.addLight(light);

    // mObjectGroup.setScale(3);
    addChild(mObjectGroup);

    // mCameraAnim = new RotateAnimation3D(Axis.Y, 360);
    // mCameraAnim.setDuration(8000);
    // mCameraAnim.setRepeatCount(Animation3D.INFINITE);
    // mCameraAnim.setTransformable3D(mObjectGroup);
}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    super.onSurfaceCreated(gl, config);
    // mCameraAnim.start();
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
    super.onDrawFrame(glUnused);
    mObjectGroup.setRotY(mObjectGroup.getRotY() + 1);
    // mObjectGroup.setRotation(mAccValues.y, mAccValues.x, mAccValues.z);
}}
```

Regards
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a color or texture to your material/object. See here: http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2011/12/05/rajawali-tutorial-3-materials/

To tell you any more I'd have to see the OBJ text.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Do you bind the texture before you draw the object?

On many GPUs the texture must be a power of 2 as I have already explained here:

[OpenGL, Shader Model 3.3 Texturing: Black Textures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818125/opengl-shader-model-3-3-texturing-black-textures/8818391#8818391)

The effect if you don't use a power of 2 texture is the one you are experiencing, a black rendered texture.